# How can I properly modify the "href" attribute of an HTML <a> tag after the page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, jinja2

I'm creating a Flask "Reddit clone" application, with one of the most critical features being the viewing and commenting of threads. When I render the HTML document to display a thread page (`thread.html`), I'm using Jinja2's `{% include %}` feature to load a sub-template (`_thread.html`), which includes an `<a>` tag allowing the user to translate different sections of the thread page. This tag should trigger a Javascript function I've written, but since a number of templates call `_thread.html` with different numbers of tags to translate, I want to modify the `<a>` tag's `href` attribute in the calling templates, but can't figure out how to do this.

As shown in my below code for my main, calling template (`thread.html`), I attempted to use JQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){})` construct to wait for the DOM to be loaded, and then call my Javascript function, passing a list of tags to translate for the specific template I'm rendering. I tried to use both the `.attr()` function and `$.click` function, but neither of these modified the link tag; the `href` attribute remains as the dummy `#` value that the sub-template says.

`app/templates/thread.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*$('#translate_thread_link{{ thread.id }}').attr('href',"javascript:translate(
                                                                        ['#thread_title{{ thread.id }}', '#thread_body{{ thread.id }}'],
                                                                        '{{ g.locale }}',
                                                                        '#translate_thread_link{{ thread.id }}')");
            $('#translate_thread_link{{ thread.id }}').click(function() {
                translate(['#thread_title{{ thread.id }}', '#thread_body{{ thread.id }}'], '{{ g.locale }}', '#translate_thread_link{{ thread.id }}')");return false;
            });
            */
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block app_content %}
    {% include "_thread.html" %}
            <tr><td><span id="thread_body{{ thread.id }}">{{ thread.body }}</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span id="translated_thread_body{{ thread.id }}"></span></td></tr>
< Additional HTML here ... >
```

`app/templates/_thread.html`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-outer-border" align="center">
    <tbody>
        {% if thread.language and thread.language != g.locale %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="translate_thread_link{{ thread.id }}" href="#">{{ _('Translate') }}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href={{url_for('subreddit', subreddit_name=thread.subreddit.name)}}>{{ _('%(subreddit_name)s', subreddit_name=thread.subreddit.name) }}</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% set user_link %}
                <a href={{ url_for('user', username=thread.user.username) }}>{{ _('%(username)s', username=thread.user.username) }}</a>
            {% endset %}
            <td> {{ _('Posted by %(user)s %(date)s', user=user_link, date=moment(thread.date).fromNow()) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b><a id="thread_title{{ thread.id }}" href="{{ url_for('view_thread', thread_title=thread.title) }}">{{ thread.title }}</a></b></td>
        </tr>
```

`base.html`

```
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
    {{ moment.lang(g.locale) }}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function translate(targetElemIdList, destLang, translateLinkElemId) {

            // Create list of text to translate
            var sourceElemTextList = targetElemIdList.map(function(targetElemId) {
                return $(targetElemId).text();
            });

            // Maintain list of original source elements to return in case translation fails
            var sourceElemList = targetElemIdList.map(function(targetElemId) {
                return $(targetElemId);
            });

            $(translateLinkElemId).html('<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='loading.gif') }}">');
            targetElemIdList.forEach(function(targetElemId) {
                $(targetElemId).html('<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='loading.gif') }}">');
            });

            $.post('/translate', {
                text: sourceElemTextList,
                dest_language: destLang
            }).done(function(response) {
                targetElemIdList.forEach(function(targetElemId, elemIndex) {
                    $(targetElemId).replaceWith(sourceElemList(elemIndex));
                    $(targetElemId).text(sourceElemTextList(response(elemIndex)));
                });
                $(translateLinkElemId).replaceWith("<p>{{ _('Text was translated from English to your preferred language.') }}</p>");
            }).fail(function() {
                targetElemIdList.forEach(function(targetElemId, elemIndex) {
                    $(targetElemId).replaceWith(sourceElemList(elemIndex));
                });
                $(translateLinkElemId).replaceWith("<p>{{ _('Error: Could not translate the selected text.') }}</p>");
            });
        }
< Additional Javascript here ... >
```

I expect that when I navigate to a thread page, clicking the "Translate" link will trigger my Javascript `translate()` function instead of simply redirecting me to the top of the current page with the `#` link, as it currently does.

Comment: `.attr('href', 'yourRefHere.ext')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since there will be a lot of this kind of link. You can use class instead of ID then use a custom attribute to hold your data.

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <a class="translate-thread-link" href="#" data-language="English">{{ _('Translate') }}</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

then for your javascript. Using jquery you can get the value of your custom attribute and execute a code during onclick event of your link. Use preventDefault to prevent the default functionality of a link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".translate-thread-link").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var language = $(this).attr('data-language');
     alert(language);
     // execute you code here or call a function that you need.
   })
})
```

Comment: Your suggestion on how to modify my `$(document).ready()` call didn't seem to work. I used the exact same syntax as you, but replaced the `alert()` call with: ```translate(['#thread_title{{ thread.id }}', '#thread_body{{ thread.id }}'], '{{ g.locale }}', '#translate_thread_link{{ thread.id }}')'); ``` . Do you have any suggestion on how to modify this?

Comment: did you use class instead of ID? when using ID you it should be unique that's why I recommend to use class instead of ID. Next is the way you call your translate function. you can put the values of translate parameters in a custom attribute. like data-target, data-dest-lang, data-translate-link then get the value of it using jquery attr.

Comment: I didn't use the `class` attribute because I want to allow the user to make the decision to translate each thread individually. Since `id`s need to be unique, I append a thread ID to each link to accomplish this. I don't think custom data attributes are the way to go here because my sub-template does not know what fields hold text to be translated; these will be known by each of the different calling templates to this sub-template. I used a simple `console.log` call to test if my JQuery `$(document).ready` call is being fired, and it isn't. Am I setting it up wrong?

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work; it seems the only change was to use the `.click()` function exactly as you suggested, instead of modifying the `href` attribute as I was trying to do. I'm unsure why this attribute modification didn't work as I've seen it asked many times on SO, but thanks for the working fix!